# DocuSign - Do PowerForms Support Webhooks/Connect

Tags: docusignapi

I haven't used DocuSign PowerForms before but have used Connect to receive notifications for envelope status updates from API generated signing requests. I'm trying to find out if PowerForms will also send notifications to a Connect listener for new events such as when someone completes a PowerForm document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they do. 
The reason is simple - PowerForms eventually just expose the same functionality, an envelope is created and it using all the other features of DocuSign including Connect.
You can set it up on the template from which the Powerform was created, or you can set it as an account-level connect configuration, both options should work.

Comment: OK thanks. If I've already created the PowerForm can I add the Webhook to the Template that I used or is to too late by then and I have to set it at the account-level?

Comment: You can do either one I believe, but the one in the template has to be done via the API, the account-level can be done via the web app.